# Code Igniter pagination with sql server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, limit

I'm working with CI pagination helper with my SQL Server 2008 db.

Where my function on the model is:

```
function get_data($limit, $offset) {
    $billing_db = $this -> load -> database('billing', TRUE);

    $billing_db -> select('stuff, stuff2, stuff3');
    $billing_db -> from('mytable');
    $billing_db -> limit($limit, $offset);
    $this -> db -> order_by("id", "asc");
    $q = $billing_db -> get();

    return $q;
}
```

Now on my controller I called the function like:

```
$data['billers'] = $this -> billing_model -> get_data(10, $this -> uri -> segment(3));
```

And when I open the page on default it displays 10 entries correctly.

Then the problem starts when I change the page, lets say I click next.
Now the url segment 3 is 10. which should start on the 10th entry and limit by 10.

But whats happening is it starts from entry 1 and displays 20 records.
Everytime the offset goes higher it just displays more records starting from the begining.

What could be wrong?

```
/**
 * Limit string
 *
 * Generates a platform-specific LIMIT clause
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   string  the sql query string
 * @param   integer the number of rows to limit the query to
 * @param   integer the offset value
 * @return  string
 */
function _limit($sql, $limit, $offset)
{
    $i = $limit + $offset;

    return preg_replace('/(^\SELECT (DISTINCT)?)/i','\\1 TOP '.$i.' ', $sql);
}
```

Comment: I imagine the reason you're getting more and more records is that _limit() is adding the offset and limit to use in the query. Thus your pages are querying SELECT TOP 10, SELECT TOP 20, SELECT TOP 30, etc as you go through them. I don't have enough experience with SQL Server 2008 to know how to do offset properly though.

Answer (score 4):

The _limit function in sqlsrv_driver and mssql_driver doesn't work properly with offset. I believe this will be fixed once CI 3 is released, but so far the best solution I have found is this:

```
function _limit($sql, $limit, $offset)
{       
    if (count($this->ar_orderby) > 0)
    {
        $OrderBy  = "ORDER BY ";
        $OrderBy .= implode(', ', $this->ar_orderby);

        if ($this->ar_order !== FALSE)
        {
            $OrderBy .= ($this->ar_order == 'desc') ? ' DESC' : ' ASC';
        }
    }

    $sql = preg_replace('/(\\'. $OrderBy .'\n?)/i','', $sql);
    $sql = preg_replace('/(^\SELECT (DISTINCT)?)/i','\\1 row_number() OVER ('.$OrderBy.') AS rownum, ', $sql);

    $NewSQL = "SELECT * \nFROM (\n" . $sql . ") AS A \nWHERE A.rownum BETWEEN (" .($offset + 1) . ") AND (".($offset + $limit).")";

    return     $NewSQL;
}
```

Posted by yangh here: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160626/